# SQL Server v14 - Login Failure

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-authentication

We are using SQL server 2014,  we update a password for a user login here

[image]

we click properties on a given login account and change the password here

[image]

we are certain we entering it correctly when we then try to login to the server using the login and password we get the following error

[image]

I don't know where else to look and what else to change -- when we do the same process on a different server it works without issue. But here its failing.

Where should we look and what else do we need to troubleshoot. Could it be we don't have access to certain databases, how do we fix this.

These are some of the errors coming through in the system logs

Message
Login failed for user ‘abc’. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database ‘AMS'. [CLIENT---]

Message
Login failed for user 'abc’. Reason: Failed to open the database ‘Budget’ specified in the login properties. [CLIENT: ---]

Message
Login failed for user ‘abc’. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ----]

Comment: Is the target database containment: partial or none ?

Comment: Look carefully at the error message, though: cannot open user *default* database. What is the user's default database, and is the login present there?

Comment: Look at the SQL Server's logs for the true authentication error. If you don't understand it, then [edit] it into your question.

Comment: @ronchi82 where can find the answer to that question - what query/setting do i need to review

Comment: Also, you state v14 on the title but 2014 in the question; what version are you really using? Version 14 (2017) or version 12 (2014)?

Comment: @YelizavetaYR , if you have admin rights, in management studio right click on the database> properties > tab option, > then the fourth option.
It's easier try the solution for what i think it is: when you try to login in the problematic database, click in options >tab connection properties> and explicity write the name of the target database. Prints and more details :https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/10/05/sql-server-connecting-specific-database-starting-ssms/

Comment: @Larnu i added some of the errors coming back

Comment: @ronchi82 there are multiple databases on the server in question.  I picked one such database and under containment it shows language, nested triggers, noise words, cuttoff ... nothing about it being partial orn one.

Comment: *"Password did not match that for the login provided."* The password is wrong it seems.

Comment: @Larnu sadly that we've triple checked so the password should be correct. The question besides in the setting above do we need to check somewhere else, do we need to drop users out there or something that may be connected. is there another step

Comment: @YelizavetaYR here's a print of the info i looking for https://www.sqlshack.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/word-image-89.png

Comment: @ronchi82 - its set to None. sorry i'm still learning all this

Comment: @JeroenMostert how do I determine the default database. I've got a server which we need to connect to and on it several databases. The login has to exist on the server or the database? (i thought server).

Comment: If the instance is saying it's wrong, the. It's wrong @ronchi82 . I would suggest changing the password and trying to new one. If that fails again, check the logs for the new error again.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR no problem, but unfortunately it's not what i was thiking...

Answer (score 0):

You must set a *default database* where the user AND relative login can access.

Logins are *objects* with a password
Users are *objects*, mapped to Logins, added to SQL Server entities.

- Under Server   -> Security -> Logins
- Unser Database -> Security -> Users

Check also if the user is correctly mapped to the login.

To solve your problem you can set the *master* database as the default for your login.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more about the error in the SQLServer logs as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16.

If you are looking for a quick fix to your problem, you can either:

- assign more server roles to your login
- or grant it an individual permission

```
use master;
grant CONNECT ANY DATABASE TO <login>;
```